# can a doctrine entity have multiple one to one relationships where from and to fields are similar?

Tags: symfony, indexing, doctrine, entity-relationship, one-to-one

```
class Order{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="order_id", type="bigint")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $orderId;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="OrderDiscount")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="order_id")
     */
    private $discount;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="OrderTax")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="order_id")
     */
    private $tax;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="OrderPayments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="order_id")
     */
    private $payment;
}

class OrderDiscount{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="order_id", type="bigint")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="discount", type="float", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=false)
     */
    private $discount;
}

class OrderPayments{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="order_id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="payment_amount", type="float", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=true)
     */
    private $paymentAmount;
}

class OrderTax{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="order_id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tax_amount", type="float", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=false)
     */
    private $taxAmount;
}
```

Here is my code (showing just basic code here).
when i migrate this schema doctrine says that an index is already exists, when i check in database that index do not exist.
Because doctrine in using column names to generate indexes, because all associations have same columns thats why doctrine says index already exists.

Is there any other better way to do this?

Comment: I can't see any index here apart the implicit one for ids. Can you show us the error?

Comment: Here both `JoinColumn`  and `referencedColumn` have same name, `order_id`. It is better to change the `refencedColumnName`, something like `discount_id`, `tax_id`..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way to do this.

What you are trying to do, simply does not work because doctrine tries to create a **foreign key from the "order_id" column from Order entity `s table** that point to each of the "order_id" columns of Discount, Tax, Payments entities' tables.

What you actually want is to **make the primary key order_id** from Order to be a **foreign key and also a primary key on Discount, Tax and Payments tables**.

To achieve this:

- Make the relation [Bidirectional](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional)
- Define the [owning side](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#bidirectional-associations) on the Discount, Tax and Payments entities.

Here is the code:

```
class Order{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="order_id", type="bigint")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $orderId;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="OrderDiscount", mappedBy="orderId")
     */
    private $discount;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="OrderTax")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="order_id")
     */
    private $tax;

}

class OrderDiscount{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Order", inversedBy="discount")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="order_id")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $orderId;


    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="discount", type="float", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=false)
     */
    private $discount;
}

class OrderTax{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Order", inversedBy="tax")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="order_id")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $orderId;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tax_amount", type="float", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=false)
     */
    private $taxAmount;
}
```

Note

- that [ORM\JoinColumn](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_joincolumn) is used on the owning side, so you do not need this your Order entity relation fields definition.
- You do not need `@ORM\Column(name="order_id", type="bigint", nullable=false)` on Discount, Tax, Payments as it is defined as a foreign key and it will be created as the same type as the column it "points" to(in this case order_id of Order).